# What is the best way to show loading screen on every components when component is not fully rendered WITHOUT REPEATING CODES

Tags: reactjs, loading, dry, higher-order-components

I am developing a mobile react web application.

Right now, I need to develop a loading screen when component is not fully rendered because you know some of my components could be heavy to load fast due to network problem, problem with mobile or other problems.

I know I can draw loading screen like so:

```
class Example1 extends React.Components{
   state={loaded:false}
   componentDidMount(){
     this.setState({loaded:true});
    }
   render(){
     if(!this.state.loaded){ return(<Loading/>)}
     else{ return( <div>Loaded!</div>)}
   }
}
```

Problem with this code is, I should repeat the same algorithms in all components. It totally ignores DRY and really messy if there already exists some conditional statements inside render().

So in conclusion, I want to show Loading screen without repeating codes on every components. Should I use HOC? What is the best option?

Comment: Put loader in redux. And just dispatch action to enable loading anywhere.

Comment: Putting a loader in redux will not dispense you to add a loader to the scaffolding of a single component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various choices, IMHO the best approach to handle it with Loadable taking advantage of async Import(). This will let you both keep DRY approach and code splitting:

**Example:**

```js
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loading from './my-loading-component';

const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./my-component'),
  loading: Loading,
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableComponent/>;
  }
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

Comment: This is actually a nice approach.

Comment: Should I return LoadableComponent on every components or is it ok just return on  root component?

Comment: Just import /pathToMyComponent/Loadable instead of /pathToMyComponent

Comment: Take a look at the implementation in react-boilerplate https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/tree/master/app/containers/HomePage

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini thanks for great answer and refs. I read through refts and your answer but have one problem which I did not understand. As I understand with your code, perhaps LoadableComponent works only on my-component file and class App.  Now I have 4 paths. How to apply this LoadableComponent on my all paths?

Comment: You have various choice, tale a look at Loadable.map()